# JSON formatting for 3 layer nest

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to achieve an jquery code that automatically fills in the select box with a name and an ID to the next select box (if the logic is correct). I am having issues structuring my JSON file.

I have the following attributes but it requires a 3 layer nested json:

Static Element (first thing on the html page)

```
<select>
<option value="first">This is the first</option>
<option value="second">This is the second</option>
<option value="third">This is the third</option>
<option value="fourth">This is the fourth</option>
<option value="fifth">This is the fifth</option>
</select>
```

So i have one static element where the user has to select the first option

```
{
    "first":[
        "london"[
            "id" = "london"
            "name" = "London UK"
            {
                "id" = "firstlondon",
                "name" = "First London"
            },
            {
                "id" = "secondlondon",
                "name" = Second London
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

So the logic is that the customer will select the `first` element from the static select box, that will display the second layer of json file, which is `London` (i need the ID and the name to be generated so they can be populated within the next select option). Finally, when the person selects the location, it displays the third json.

I have worked out the jquery, just not how to formulate the json.

Comment: How could you have worked out the jQuery if the data isn't in the right format?

Comment: i have worked out how to display on a 2 layer json so adding another `each` function wouldnt be to hard. just confused how to format my json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is valid JSON formatted for the example that you gave. I would have to know a little bit more about your data in order to truly understand if this is a proper representation of your data.

I use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) if I do anything crazy with JSON or get really long files, it really helps me see what's going on. I'd recommend running your data through here, it usually catches a missing brace or bracket and REALLY helps if you miss a comma in my experience.

```
{
    "first": [
        {
            "london": [
                {
                    "id": "london",
                    "name": "London UK",
                    "london": [
                        {
                            "id": "london",
                            "name": "London UK"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "secondLondon",
                            "name": "Second London"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "second": [
        {
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```